# How to get information of dropped frames and resolution of the played video from Video player like VLC

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, metadata, video-processing

I was playing 360° videos using [whirligig](http://www.whirligig.xyz/) player for my subjective test and I was wondering how can I get the information of dropped frames and resolution of video played by the player. 
The source resolution of the video is 1080p, and the frame rate is 30fps

When I watching videos on YouTube, I am able to derive the above information by right clicking and looking at the 'stats for nerds' option - see example below:

[image]

But didn't get the required information for the videos played on [whirligig](http://www.whirligig.xyz/) player such as dropped frames, actual bitrate playable on the player and playable resolution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you checked the [YouTube Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=en) - the `statistics` section? - at the end of the page.

Comment: This will not help me. I am talking about players like VLC.

Comment: Can you add an example in your question?, the image provided in your questions belongs to "statistics for nerds", but I really don't know how VLC player shows. It will helpul too for anyone else who wants help you.

Comment: I edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: Unfortunately no, at least, not for me. I recommend you add an screenshot about which information is shown in the VLC player. If you're thinking in get these information from videos that aren't yours, YouTube Data API wont give you more details *(as far as I know)*.

Comment: VLC has it in tools->codec information->statistics. Whirlgig just dont seem to have such a feature, better to ask the vendor for it, maybe you run lucky and they add the feature for you

Comment: @AshutoshSingla If your question is not about VLC then you should change the title. If you're asking _"where to click"_ on Whirligig to see info about device screen resolution vs video resolution then it doesn't exist in Whirligig player. Are you using any programming language that can query such info before running the Whirligig player? Or specify what problem you need to solve by knowing this video info (maybe there is an alternative solution outside of Whirligig's options)...

Answer (score 0):

Google's "stats for nerds" does not specify the source of the dropped frames, network or render pipelines.

You must query VLC's API for unfilled buffers for the network delay. I am not aware of the API call to get the rendering delay/overrun count.

Answer (score 0):

Another overlooked option is the excellent `ffplay` - see http://www.ffmpeg.org

Start ffplay from the command line using `ffplay -stats <videofile>` - you will find plenty of stats and playback info in the both the command line and as an overlay.